# Flutter Local Notifications Plugin: How to automatically count active notification

Tags: flutter, notifications, counter, local

I am using Flutter Local Notifications Plugin to schedule notifications on demand in my app.

1. The notifications work fine and arrive as scheduled.
2. The onSelectNotification executes fine when the particular notification is selected.
   ...
   await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
   initializationSettings,
   onSelectNotification: selectNotification
   );
   ...
3. I have a method to count active notifications as following:
   Future activeNotificationCount() async {
   final List activeNotifications =
   await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
   .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
   AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
   ?.getActiveNotifications();
   return activeNotifications.length;
   }

How do I automatically count active local notifications as they execute?, I had no success using onSelectNotification as it only executes when selected. however, I have noticed that onSelectNotification is automatically executed when a scheduled local notification arrives while the state of the application is 'paused'. please, can anybody help?

Many Thanks in advance,

Tewfik

Comment: hey! I am facing the same problem. Here is the link to my question in case anybody answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974031/flutter-local-notifications-onnotificationreceived-method-flutter